# Cosa sono gli "zezzilli"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Il bambino si chiamava Senjeley Pshimaqua come il marito circasso che era morto di tubercolosi tanto tempo prima, e non cresceva perché anche se se lo teneva attaccato agli **zezzilli** per ore, finché le facevano male, non tirava nemmeno una goccia, in quanto il latte lei non ce l’aveva.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "zezzillo"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato.
Immagino si tratti di un termine di origine regionale. Dovete sapere che i protagonisti di questo romanzo sono emigrati italiani a New York, provenienti da Minturno e, a quanto pare, il [dialetto minturnese](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minturno) deriva dalla lingua napoletana.

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere la ragione del voto negativo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gli ***[zezzilli](https://books.google.it/books?id=kUcIRKwCZF4C&pg=PA528&lpg=PA528&dq=zezzilli%20capezzoli&source=bl&ots=4B5wzfQY9m&sig=ACfU3U3ZDNygaDkpBM4QV4EiWuVzpBUisg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2v__ej5HjAhVyRBUIHUw2CmAQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=zezzilli%20capezzoli&f=false)*** sono i ***capezzoli***, come si può capire anche dal testo del brano.

(Fonte del link: *Vocabolario etimologico odierno napoletano-italiano* di D. Erwin e P. Bello)